# How to show partial content of a page on another in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page called Dashboard and would like to show the contents of say page A and B on the Dashboard page. I can achieve this with the following code but I only want to show partial content of A and B like snippets. How can I show this in exactly the same styling as it appears on page A and B ?

```
function show_post($path) {
 $post = get_page_by_path($path);
 $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
 echo $content;
}

<?php show_post('pageA');  // Shows the content of the "PageA" page. ?>
<?php show_post('pageB');  // Shows the content of the "PageB" page. ?>
```

Page A shows the content with this code:

```
 <ul class="leftlist">
        <?php
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        ?>
        <li class="todo" id="<?php echo get_the_ID();?>" itemage="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_todotime',true)?>"><a href="javascript:;"
        <?php if($all_meta_for_user[get_the_ID()][0]){              
        ?>
        class="strike"
        <?php
         }
        ?>
        >           
        <?php if($all_meta_for_user[get_the_ID()][0]){?>
            <span class="check_box cb"></span>
            <?php }else{?>
        <span class="uncheck_box cb"></span>
        <?php }?>   
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p></a>           
        <?php
        endwhile;
        ?>            
        </ul>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you just want to take a part from whole a or b page . and it will show in Dashboard page. right ?

Comment: Yes just part of it not the whole content

Comment: ok, let me type an naswer

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do this by post create 2 posts suppose A and B. it will generate id's like 20,22 ... and use this code in your pages for page A:

```
<?php  $cquery = new WP_Query('cat=20'); $i=1; ?>
      <?php if($cquery->have_posts()): while($cquery->have_posts()):  $cquery->the_post();   
      <?php the_post_thumbnail();   ?>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
      <?php $i++; endwhile; endif; endif;  ?>
```

and similarly for post B with having id 22.

Comment: Thanks..but wont this show the whole of the content for postA..I only want to show partial content. E.g I have check list on postA. Only only want to show 3 check lists rather than all of them.

Comment: so, you can explode your content in 2 parts.

Comment: <?php $cont = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content); 
              $arr = explode(".", $content);
                 $first = $arr[0];
                 echo $first; ?>

Comment: thanks..the content on pageA shows dynamic content so using the explode method wont work. See updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not extremest php coder. But i am trying it. 
Here is the code you can do it by with php `explode` .

In your page A or B just put an identifier for explode. 
Like this :

```
Here is the first of the contents of the page. 
<!--start-->
From this part you want to show something
<!--stop-->
Here is the rest of the contents
```

And then your function is like :

```
function show_post($path) {
 $post = get_page_by_path($path);
 $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
 $explode=explode('<!--start-->',$content);
 $explode=explode('<!--stop-->',$explode[1]);
 echo $explode[0];
}
```

Comment: thanks..the content on pageA shows dynamic content so using the explode method wont work. See updated question.